# Can HomeBank 4.5.6 be used to supersede 4.5.5 in the Ubuntu repository please?

Tags: update-manager

I don't know which version I used to use successfully, but I used to import QIF files from my bank into HomeBank. My computer was out of action for a couple of months, and when I got it working again I attempted to continue importing QIF files into HomeBank again (version 4.5.5 now). It didn't work, I reported a bug, I have been informed that the bug [has been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/homebank/+bug/1276377) in the next version (4.5.6) of the application on or around 16 February 2014.

I can't use the application if it can't import these files, and now it has been 3 months since it was apparently fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [latest version](http://homebank.free.fr/downloads.php) for Ubuntu can be installed with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mdoyen/homebank
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install homebank
```

The newest version source code can be found on [launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/homebank). Latest stable is [4.5.6](http://homebank.free.fr/public/homebank-4.5.6.tar.gz) (direct download). The download has an installation script. Relevant part:

The simplest way to compile this package is:

1. `cd` to the directory containing the package's source code and type
    `./configure` to configure the package for your system.

   Running `configure` might take a while.  While running, it prints
    some messages telling which features it is checking for.
2. Type `make` to compile the package.
3. Optionally, type `make check` to run any self-tests that come with
    the package.
4. Type `make install` to install the programs and any data files and
    documentation.
5. You can remove the program binaries and object files from the
    source code directory by typing `make clean'.  To also remove the
    files that`configure`created (so you can compile the package for
    a different kind of computer), type`make distclean`.  There is
    also a`make maintainer-clean` target, but that is intended mainly
    for the package's developers.  If you use it, you may have to get
    all sorts of other programs in order to regenerate files that came
    with the distribution.
6. Often, you can also type `make uninstall` to remove the installed
    files again.

Comment: Thanks. I added the PPA and updated the application that way. It's too much work to compile from source code, although I appreciate the 'how-to'.